# React Native Back button disappears after using StackAction reset

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

It resets to StackAction and comes in a main component with four tabs.

If you navigate to another page in the main tab, no back button is created in the header.

The header is also not editable.

**Go to main tab**

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
 index: 0,
 actions: [
  NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'MainTab'}),
 ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

**Tab1 -> other Component**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('OtherCompo');
```

**navigator.js**

```
const OtherScene = createStackNavigator({
 OtherCompo: {screen: OtherCompo}
})

const MainScene = createStackNavigator({
 MainTab: {screen: MainTab},
 OtherScene: {screen: OtherScene}
})

const loginScene = createStackNavigator({
 LoginUI: {screen:LoginUI},
 MainScene: {screen:MainScene}
})
```

Comment: Can you please share your code of navigator? where have you defined `MainTab` and `OtherCompo` in navigation?

Comment: <navigator.js> The navigator and tabnavigator are separate, and the above code is as simple as possible.